# How to get specific data from a JSON weather API in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

My set is like this:

```
const [info, setInfo] = useState([]);

const getWeather = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${query}&appid=${API_KEY}`);
        const data = await response.json();
        setInfo(data);
        console.log('info...', data);
    }
```

And I am getting data back:

```
info... {coord: {…}, weather: Array(1), base: "stations", main: {…}, visibility: 16093, …}

base: "stations"
clouds:
all: 1
__proto__: Object
cod: 200
coord: {lon: -122.9, lat: 38.55}
dt: 1590009043
id: 5397100
main: {temp: 295.58, feels_like: 292.91, temp_min: 293.15, temp_max: 297.59, pressure: 1019, …}
name: "Sonoma"
sys: {type: 1, id: 5933, country: "US", sunrise: 1589979335, sunset: 1590031263}
timezone: -25200
visibility: 16093
weather: Array(1)
0: {id: 800, main: "Clear", description: "clear sky", icon: "01d"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
wind: {speed: 4.1, deg: 190}
```

For example name, timezone  I have been able to render easily, since all the data is inside of info. I just put `{info.name}` and in this case I get Sonoma ...but how do I get what's inside of weather? I want the description. If I click on weather this is what I get:

```
weather: Array(1)
0: {id: 800, main: "Clear", description: "clear sky", icon: "01d"}
```

I have tried `{info.weather[0].description}` but I get this error every time:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Is the error coming from the initial render, before the async call has finished?

Comment: When you are trying to access info.weather[0].description are you sure that the call to the API has completed and returned? What you can do is put a breakpoint on the line immediately after the `const data = await response.json()` and see what the value of `data` is. If it contains the properties you expect, then you're probably just trying to use it before it's been set.

Comment: it does contain all the properties....so I put data inside of setInfo(data) ...and I have it set up like this .....const [info, setInfo] = useState([]) ... I have def getting all the data I need back ..just dont know how to render whats inside of weather....I am not sure if {info.weather[0].description}  is right way ...thats just what I thought might work.

Comment: weather: Array(1) 0: {id: 800, main: "Clear", description: "clear sky", icon: "01d"} ...def getting back data ...description say clear sky ....I just want to be able to render description

Comment: _Please_ learn the formatting tools here before asking a new question. Code should always be block-formatted for readability.

Comment: judging by the error, info itself is already undefined.

info.weather[0].description would be the correct way of accessing it, but only when info is actually not undefined.

Please show a bit more context.

What function is retrieving the data, and how do you pass it on to the component rendering it?

It's very likely there's an issue with the way you are passing on the data. Probably forgetting an await or something.

Comment: thanks guys I figured out a way to render it ..and def need to learn about formatting tools before asking a question again....I realized the way I asked question wasnt much help...thanks again for taking the time to help out.

Comment: Shouldn't it be ```data.weather[0].description``` instead of ```info.weather[0].description```? Ah, ok. You update the state with it and then access it. But as it is an object now, wouldn't it make more sense to initialise it as an object instead of an array?